# cannot invoke * with an argument list of type ($T12, @lvalue CGFloat)

Tags: ios, swift

The title is the error message that I receive compiling this line:

```
 let width : Float   = mainView.frame.size.width / 100.0 * value
```

The `value` variable is of `Float` type. What's wrong here?

Comment: btw, Apple, what the heck is $T12? Some kind of internal id? Wouldn't it be better if the message said "no operator * was found for argument types float and CGFloat"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> cannot invoke * with an argument list of type ($T12, @lvalue CGFloat)

Read answer in error:

`mainView.frame.size.width` has type `CGFloat` therefore you need cast `CGFloat` to `Float`

Try to set `value` as `CGFloat` or cast `Float(image.size.width)`

---

*In playground*

<kbd>Option 1</kbd>

```
let image = UIImage(named:"group_1.png") // just for example

let value:CGFloat = 10.0

let width:Float   = Float(image.size.width / 100.0 * value)
```

<kbd>Option 2</kbd>

```
let value:Float = 10.0
let width:Float   = Float(image.size.width) / 100.0 * value
```